# How to get a value stored in a request and can be read in the collection's pre-request script in Postman?

Tags: postman, postman-pre-request-script

I am doing authentication for all the requests in the collection's pre-request script. The url for the authentication is dynamically created based on some criteria in the request but only in Postman. It doesn't get sent with the request.

I can't set an environment or global variable in the request's pre-request script because it runs *after* the collection's pre-request script. So that's too late.

I can't put the value as a request parameter or in the request's url because it will be part of the request itself that gets sent out. I was looking for an area in Postman, like a request tag or some kind of metadata, in the request to hold a specific value that can be read in the collection's pre-request script.

Is there anything in Postman to read such a value that can be read in a pre-request script?